# ASCII art on website

Tags: javascript, html, ascii-art

I'm trying to get some ASCII art on my website with a JavaScript function but the result isn't what I'm looking for right now...

This is how it should look:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/qHXxLtU.png]

And here is the code I'm using to try to achieve that:

```js
function log( text ) {
  $log = $('#log');
  //Add text to log
  $log.append(($log.val()?"":'')+ text );
  //Autoscroll
  $log[0].scrollTop = $log[0].scrollHeight - $log[0].clientHeight;
}
      
      
log('<div style="font-family: monospace; white-space: pre;">' + 
    "  _______                              <br>" +
    " |__   __|                             <br>" +
    "    | | ___  _ __ ___  _ __ ___  _   _ <br>" +
    "    | |/ _ \| '_ ` _ \| '_ ` _ \| | | |<br>" +
    "    | | (_) | | | | | | | | | | | |_| |<br>" +
    "    |_|\___/|_| |_| |_|_| |_| |_|\__, |<br>" +
    "                                  __/ |<br>" +
    "                                 |___/ <br>"  +
    
    "<br>" +
     "</div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Hope you guys come up with a better result than I did because this is not working at all for me right now.

Comment: Have you tried escaping your backslashes with another backslash?  So for instance every time you have a single \, like for instance in the right side of the top of the "O" character, you'd have \\ instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you must note that in strings if you want to print '\' character, you must use '\\' instead :)

```js
function log( text ) {
    $log = $('#log');
    //Add text to log
    $log.append(($log.val()?"":'')+ text );
    //Autoscroll
    $log[0].scrollTop = $log[0].scrollHeight - $log[0].clientHeight;
}


log('<div style="font-family: monospace; white-space: pre;">' +
    "  _______                              <br>" +
    " |__   __|                             <br>" +
    "    | | ___  _ __ ___  _ __ ___  _   _ <br>" +
    "    | |/ _ \\| '_ ` _ \\| '_ ` _ \\| | | |<br>" +
    "    | | (_) | | | | | | | | | | | |_| |<br>" +
    "    |_|\\___/|_| |_| |_|_| |_| |_|\\__, |<br>" +
    "                                  __/ |<br>" +
    "                                 |___/ <br>"  +

    "<br>" +
    "</div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: You should not just say "_change letter spacing property_" - you should show an example of the code for it that will solve the problem.

Comment: This answer should have been a comment

Comment: This solved my problem with Tommy but now i have a new text with the same problem and i tried to change them without any results :S


Here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/0snvu7e6/

Comment: just note that you must replace all '\' characters with '\\' , you can do this in your new shape, this will correct your ascii art :) can you please close this question ?

Comment: @ArashKhajelou sorry i forgot i had the question and then went to sleep now i closed it, thank u all!

Answer (score 2):

Would the HTML `<pre>` tag work for you as an alternate solution?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre

Edit: You do need to escape your backslashes if you plan to use them in a JS string, as the comment and other answer mentions.

Live example of `pre`:

```html
<pre >
 ______
&lt; Moo! &gt;
 ------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
</pre>
```

(Based on output from https://jshields.github.io/cowsay.club/)

Answer (score 2):

In ECMAScript 6, [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) come to the rescue with the template tag function [`String.raw()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw):

```js
function log(text) {
  $log = $('#log');
  //Add text to log
  $log.append(($log.val() ? "" : '') + text);
  //Autoscroll
  $log[0].scrollTop = $log[0].scrollHeight - $log[0].clientHeight;
}


log('<div style="font-family: monospace; white-space: pre;">' +
  String.raw `  _______                              <br>` +
  String.raw ` |__   __|                             <br>` +
  String.raw `    | | ___  _ __ ___  _ __ ___  _   _ <br>` +
  String.raw `    | |/ _ \| '_ ' _ \| '_ ' _ \| | | |<br>` +
  String.raw `    | | (_) | | | | | | | | | | | |_| |<br>` +
  String.raw `    |_|\___/|_| |_| |_|_| |_| |_|\__, |<br>` +
  String.raw `                                  __/ |<br>` +
  String.raw `                                 |___/ <br>` +
  "<br>" +
  "</div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
```

(Unfortunately I had to replace the two backticks with single quotes in the m's in order for this to work)